# Bash doesn't recognize php

Tags: php, linux, bash

Even though I have php in my /usr/bin and it is in my PATH when using bash it doesn't find php.

```
bash: php: command not found
```

And here is `echo $PATH`:

```
/home/adnan/.local/bin:/home/adnan/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/adnan/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/node_modules/bin
```

I am using Fedora 34 Workstation.

Comment: what is the output of `type -a php`

Comment: @Jetchisel It is strange that when I run my terminal (gnome-terminal) the output for the command is `php is /us/bin/php` but when using bash in vs code or phpstorm the output is `bash: type: php: not found`

Comment: Well, that is a configuration issue with vscode I suppose, so no programming question/issue here.

Comment: @Jetchisel not only vs code or phpstorm. even if I run bash or sh externally, the issue is still there.

Comment: @Jetchisel and for more details I've moved to `usr/bin` and listed the files using `ls` when running in terminal it shows that php exists. But in bash in the same folder the php file doesn't exist.

Comment: PATH is per shell instance. Please do `echo "$PATH"` in the same shell where the command fails.

Comment: @thatotherguy Here is the output: `/home/adnan/.local/bin:/home/adnan/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/adnan/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/node_modules/bin`

Comment: So you are saying that `/usr/bin/php` does not exist on the file system when you look via the shell you get from vscode? This suggests that the shell is in a docker image, VM, chroot, remote system, or otherwise doesn't share files with your local machine.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes exactly. And the stranger thing is that even other stuff such as sudo and many commands are not listed. So how can I solve it given that your assumption is correct?

Comment: @Shadow4Kill : So, if php does not exist on your platform, how can you expect that bash will find it? How about installing php, before using it? (Just an idea....)

Comment: @user1934428 I believe you misunderstood my problem. I've posted the solution below describing what was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @thatotherguy I've looked out and found the problem and I am posting here if anyone lands in this post and is looking for an answer.

Since I've installed PhpStorm and VSCode using flatpak and they are running inside a container they cannot access hosts' commands. To execute command from the host it is needed to use the command below:

```
flatpak-spawn --host <COMMAND>
```